# Python telnet connection refuse exception

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using following function to make telnet connection verification

```
telnetlib.Telnet("172.28.5.240", "8080")
```

When the connection refused it shows exception message. Is it possible to hide the message and detect as success or failed through if condition?

Comment: As in, catching the thrown exception?

Comment: Perhaps start here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use try-except-finally blocks

```
 try:
     #
     #
     response = 'Success'
 except:
     response = 'Failed'
 finally:
     print response
```

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Suku's answer I develop my code. that is a working answer. And following is my script for reference.

```
try:
    conn = telnetlib.Telnet("172.28.5.240", "80")
    response = 'Success'
except:
    response = 'Failed'
finally:
    print response
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the options helped me.
Maybe someone will come in handy.
100% working version:
Used to check the availability of the RDP server in ZABBIX:

```
import telnetlib
response = ''
HOST = '192.168.1.201'
PORT = 3389
tn = telnetlib.Telnet()
try:
    tn.open(HOST, PORT, 3)
    response = '2'
except Exception:
    response = '0'
finally:
    tn.close()
    print(response)
```